# I don't understand the mathematical meaning of mse value in lscov function for matlab

Tags: matlab, regression, least-squares, linear-regression

We have the following system

$$Y = A X$$

Using least-squares, an estimate of $X$ is

$$\widehat{X} = (A^H A)^{-1} A^H Y$$

And thus the [*mean square error*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) for me is:

$$\mbox{MSE} = \mathbb E[ \|(Y - A\cdot{}\widehat{X})\|^2 ]$$

But looking at [lscov](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lscov.html) routine of matlab, they seems to define returned `mse` parameter as:

$$MSE_{lscov} = \frac{Y^H \cdot{}(Y - A\cdot{}\widehat{X})}{m-n}$$

Where $m$ and $n$ is the size of matrix $A$.

I clearly don't understand what is the meaning of $MSE_{lscov}$ and how it relates to what I call the *mean square error* ?

---

For instance with

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1.0000 & 0.2000 & 0.1000\\ 
1.0000 & 0.5000 & 0.3000\\
1.0000 &  0.6000 & 0.4000\\
1.0000 &  0.8000 & 0.9000\\
1.0000 &  1.0000 & 1.1000\\
1.0000 &  1.1000 & 1.4000\\
\end{bmatrix}$

and

$Y = \begin{bmatrix}
0.1700\\
0.2600\\
0.2800\\
0.2300\\
0.2700\\
0.3400
\end{bmatrix}$

I get:

$MSE = 0.00077279766...$

$MSE_{lscov} = 0.00154559...$

$\frac{Y^H \cdot{}(Y - A\cdot{}\widehat{X})}{m-n} = MSE_{lscov} = 0.00154559...$

Comment: What is $Y^H$ ?

Comment: @A.E This is the transpose conjugate of $Y$

Comment: MSE is short for Mean Squared Error. Usually the error, squared and then mean value of that square over all the elements you try to fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the original data matrix, $Y$ is the dependent variable and $\beta$ is the unknown coefficients. Namely, your model is $Y=X\beta+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. As such, $\epsilon^2 =(Y-X\beta)^2$. So, $\sigma^2 = var(\epsilon) = \mathbb{E}\epsilon^2 = \mathbb{E}(Y-X\beta)^2$. Thus when you estimate $\beta$ by specifying some model, you can compute its MSE, that is 
$$
MSE = \mathbb{E}||Y-X\hat{\beta}||^2.
$$
Hence you have to estimate it with an appropriate statistic, which intuitively would be 
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - \hat{y})^2,
$$
however, although it is asymptotically consistent estimator, it is biased for every finite $n$. So, you can view
$$
\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n-m}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - \hat{y})^2,
$$
where $m$ is the number of coefficients in the model, or similarly the column dimension of the data matrix $X'X$ (or $A'A$ in your notations), as the unbiased modified estimator of the real MSE ($\sigma^2$). Intuitively, you loose one degree of freedom for every estimated $\beta$. By doing some simple algebra you can get 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - \hat{y})^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - \hat{y})(y_i - \hat{y}) = \sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - \hat{y})y_i - \sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - \hat{y})\hat{y},  
$$ 
where the second summand is  $0$ because $\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - \hat{y})\hat{y}=\sum_{i=1}^ne_i\hat{y}=0$.  The final equality, i.e., the orthogonality of the $e$ and $\hat{y}$ stems from the algorithm that derives the OLS estimators. So, back to matrix notation you get 
$$
\hat{MSE}=\frac{1}{n-m}Y'(Y-X\hat{\beta}).
$$

Comment: Thanks for these clarifications ... So I can consider `mse` value returned by `lscov` as the unbiased estimation of mean square error (as if i had had an infinite set of equations), right ?

Comment: Yes, it is the unbiased estimator of the real MSE (for any number of observations $n$). Actually, it is the standard way to compute the (empirical) MSE in linear regression problem like yours.

Comment: I have added some more details to the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: All clear and efficient because manually computing biased MSE was drastically slowing down my computations rather than just reading unbiased MSE from `lscov` (I have to repeat this system inversion for many frequencies).